Syncing timed camera and LED flash on Raspberry Pi
I have a Raspberry Pi 4 which I have connected to an Arducam 64MP OwlSight Auto-Focus camera (ov64a40) and 2 neopixel jewel LEDs (7 x 5050 RGBW). I need to be able to take a photo every 30 seconds over 9 hours in sync with the LEDs flashing. Ideally I would be able to save a readme doc to the SD card that I could just open and run every time and use the same application (for camera I'm using the Pi terminal and for the LEDs I'm using Python). Does anyone know how I could get them operating from the same application and synced?
For timed camera photos every 30 seconds over 9 hours saved with the timestamp the below code works:
libcamera-still -t 32400000 --timelapse 300000 --datetime --width 1920 --height 1080 --shutter 5000

In another terminal, I then enter a virtual environment using python to flash the LEDs every 30 seconds:
source .venv/bin/activate #Entering virtual environment
ptpython #Entering python space

import time
import board
import neopixel

pixels1 = neopixel.NeoPixel(board.D18, 7, bpp=4)
pixels2 = neopixel.NeoPixel(board.D21, 7, bpp=4)

while True:
#Turn both neopixels red
pixels1.fill((255, 0, 0))
pixels2.fill((255, 0, 0))
pixels1.show()
pixels2.show()
#Time on (seconds)
time.sleep(30)

#Turn both neopixels off
pixels1.fill((0, 0, 0))
pixels2.fill((0, 0, 0))
pixels1.show()
pixels2.show()
#Time off (seconds)
time.sleep(30)

Both codes work fine but don't automatically sync together and I have to re-type it in after I open the system. Does anyone know how I could get them synced and more user friendly for others to open the system and run?

It's not very clear what you are actually trying to do here. Take a picture with the LEDs on? Or off? It's not very clear what SD cards and README files have to do with synchronisation. Your code is also incorrectly formatted and doesn't work as posted. Indentation is significant in Python. Anyway - the most likely way to synchronise is by using a Unix "signal'. Look at the manual page for libcamera-still and SIGUSR1 inititating imagecapture. Look also at Python subprocess docs to see how to start a process and send it signals.
